# Need mx:textArea with transparent background and backgroundAlpha="0" won't work

Tags: apache-flex, background, textarea, styling, flex-spark

I have a custom component that extends `mx:TextArea`, but when I try and apply `backgroundAlpha="0"` it says

> The style 'backgroundAlpha' is only supported by type 'components.LabelEditor' with the theme(s) 'halo'.

I don't see anywhere specifying that it is not using the Halo theme, unless it has decided to extend `s:TextArea` despite my not importing it.

How can I make this component accept the style instructions or achieve a transparent background some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation on themes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f85.html):

> The default theme for Flex 4
>   components is Spark. All controls in an application built with Flex 4 use the Spark theme. Even MX controls have a Spark look and feel in a Flex 4 application.

Also, as per the [ASDocs for mx:TextArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html), when using the Spark theme there is a style named 'contentBackgroundAlpha' that can be set achieve what you seem to want out of the mx:TextArea.